# Re-using Queued Data in Python

Tags: python-2.7, stream, queue

I have a data stream that adds price information to a queue where it is consumed while processing an order.  Could someone advise on how I could save the last price streamed and only send to the queue IF the price were (for instance) higher than the last, or vice versa?

Here is my code, thanks in advance for any help!

```
def stream_to_queue(self):
        response = self.connect_to_stream()
        if response.status_code != 200:
            return
        for line in response.iter_lines(1):
            if line:
                try:
                    msg = json.loads(line)
                except Exception as e:
                    print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                    return
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    print msg["tick"]
                    instrument = msg["tick"]["instrument"]
                    time = msg["tick"]["time"]
                    bid = msg["tick"]["bid"]
                    ask = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                    stop = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                    tev = TickEvent(instrument, time, bid, ask)
                    self.events_queue.put(tev)
```

Comment: Can't you use a class member to store the previous value and compare to the current value ?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, just not sure how to implement.  I'll give it a shot and post my attempt..  Thanks